# NSPC bathroom venting Diagram Correct?

Tags: plumbing, venting

I will start a description from the top of the page. The label there says vent and it goes up to the roof (2 stories). Right beside it is a 3" stack that is carrying the waste from a full bathroom which is completely vented also to the roof.

Both come down and enter beneath the concrete slab. The 3" sewer is 6 inches below the 2" vent. Both of them follow the 1/4" slope required.

The 3" sewer pipe has a sink tapped into it which will have an AAV. Right after a toilet connection is made, and finally a shower is connected.

The 2" line parallels all these fixtures and about a foot where the shower enters the 3" line, the vent that comes from the roof attaches to the 3" sewer pipe, it is rolled at an angle to keep it above the sewer line.

So there is a vent from the roof that is downstream from the shower, and an AAV at the sink. I called the 2" vent a wet vent, but perhaps that was in error. It goes directly to the roof.

[image]